# Закрывается cmd сразу после ответа хотя написано всё против этого Python

Tags: python

Закрывается cmd сразу после ответа хотя написано всё против этого

```
#NumTop 2
#v1.0
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()

print( "Загрузка 15%" )
print( "Загрузка 25%" )
print( "Загрузка 35%" )
print( "Загрузка 42%" )
print( "Загрузка 47%" )
print( "Загрузка 56%" )
print( "Загрузка 57%" )
print( "Загрузка 75%" )
print( "Загрузка 87%" )
print( "Загрузка 99%" )
print( "Загрузка 100%" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.BLUE )

print( "Вас приветствует NumTop 2 V1.0" )
print( "0.1 Старт программы" )
print( "0.2 Добавлен лист обновлений, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.3 Добавлен знак умножения, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.4 Добавлен знак деления, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.6 Добавлено двух значное действие +- и -+, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.7 Убраная функция -+" )
print( "0.8 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком +" )
print( "0.9 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком -" )
print( "1.0 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком * и /, обновлен интерфейс" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.GREEN )

www = input( "Выбери действие из предоставленых тебе: +, -, *, /, +-, +*, +/, ++, -+, -*, -/, --, *+, *-, */, **, /+, /*, /-, //, " ) #www = выбор действия пользователем

print( Back.YELLOW )

a = float ( input( "Введите первое число: " ) )
b = float ( input( "Введите второе число: " ) )

if www == "+":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "++":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "--":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "**":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "//":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
else:
    print( "Ошибка" )
    print( "Ваш результат: ..." )
    input()
    input() #Предохранитель

print( Back.GREEN )

print( "Спасибо за использование нашего сервиса :) " )
primt( "NumTop 2" )
print( "ВК разработчика: https://vk.com/danilkadrakon" )

input()
input() #Предохранитель
```

```
#NumTop 2
#v1.0
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()

print( "Загрузка 15%" )
print( "Загрузка 25%" )
print( "Загрузка 35%" )
print( "Загрузка 42%" )
print( "Загрузка 47%" )
print( "Загрузка 56%" )
print( "Загрузка 57%" )
print( "Загрузка 75%" )
print( "Загрузка 87%" )
print( "Загрузка 99%" )
print( "Загрузка 100%" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.BLUE )

print( "Вас приветствует NumTop 2 V1.0" )
print( "0.1 Старт программы" )
print( "0.2 Добавлен лист обновлений, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.3 Добавлен знак умножения, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.4 Добавлен знак деления, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.6 Добавлено двух значное действие +- и -+, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.7 Убраная функция -+" )
print( "0.8 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком +" )
print( "0.9 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком -" )
print( "1.0 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком * и /, обновлен интерфейс" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.GREEN )

www = input( "Выбери действие из предоставленых тебе: +, -, *, /, +-, +*, +/, ++, -+, -*, -/, --, *+, *-, */, **, /+, /*, /-, //, " ) #www = выбор действия пользователем

print( Back.YELLOW )

a = float ( input( "Введите первое число: " ) )
b = float ( input( "Введите второе число: " ) )

if www == "+":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "++":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "--":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "**":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "//":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
else:
    print( "Ошибка" )
    print( "Ваш результат: ..." )
    input()
    input() #Предохранитель

print( Back.GREEN )

print( "Спасибо за использование нашего сервиса :) " )
primt( "NumTop 2" )
print( "ВК разработчика: https://vk.com/danilkadrakon" )

input()
input() #Предохранитель
```

```
#NumTop 2
#v1.0
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()

print( "Загрузка 15%" )
print( "Загрузка 25%" )
print( "Загрузка 35%" )
print( "Загрузка 42%" )
print( "Загрузка 47%" )
print( "Загрузка 56%" )
print( "Загрузка 57%" )
print( "Загрузка 75%" )
print( "Загрузка 87%" )
print( "Загрузка 99%" )
print( "Загрузка 100%" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.BLUE )

print( "Вас приветствует NumTop 2 V1.0" )
print( "0.1 Старт программы" )
print( "0.2 Добавлен лист обновлений, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.3 Добавлен знак умножения, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.4 Добавлен знак деления, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.6 Добавлено двух значное действие +- и -+, обнавлён интерфейс" )
print( "0.7 Убраная функция -+" )
print( "0.8 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком +" )
print( "0.9 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком -" )
print( "1.0 Добавлены все двух значные действия с начальным знаком * и /, обновлен интерфейс" )

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.GREEN )

www = input( "Выбери действие из предоставленых тебе: +, -, *, /, +-, +*, +/, ++, -+, -*, -/, --, *+, *-, */, **, /+, /*, /-, //, " ) #www = выбор действия пользователем

print( Back.YELLOW )

a = float ( input( "Введите первое число: " ) )
b = float ( input( "Введите второе число: " ) )

if www == "+":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/":
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "+*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "++":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a + b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "-*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "--":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a - b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "*/":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "**":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a * b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/+":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b + d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/-":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b - d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "/*":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b * d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
elif www == "//":
    d = float ( input( "Введите третье число: " ) )
    print( Back.CYAN )
    c = a / b / d
    print( "Ваш результат:" + str(c) )
else:
    print( "Ошибка" )
    print( "Ваш результат: ..." )
    input()
    input() #Предохранитель

print( Back.GREEN )

print( "Спасибо за использование нашего сервиса :) " )
primt( "NumTop 2" )
print( "ВК разработчика: https://vk.com/danilkadrakon" )

input()
input() #Предохранитель
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в коде. Запусти в предварительно открытой консоли:

python3 путь\имяфайла.py

И посмотри нет ли ошибок.